# SQL Where clause use if value greater than

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I try create optional query.I have in sql proc 4 param.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_OdevTümBilgiler]
@ogretmenUserId int,

@ogrenciUserId int,
@odevAdi nvarchar(50) = null,
@odevId int
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SELECT
  s.*,
  o.*,
  ko.*,
  ogretmenUser.UserID AS OgretmenUserId,
  ogrenciUser.UserID AS OgrenciId,
  (ogretmenUser.Name + ' ' + ogretmenUser.Surname) AS OgretmenFullName,
  (ogrenciUser.Name + ' ' + ogrenciUser.Surname) AS OgrenciFullName
FROM KullaniciOdev AS ko
INNER JOIN Odev o
  ON ko.OdevId = o.OdevId
INNER JOIN FrUser ogrenciUser
  ON ogrenciUser.UserID = ko.UserId
INNER JOIN Sinif s
  ON s.SinifId = o.ClassId
INNER JOIN FrUser ogretmenUser
  ON ogretmenUser.UserID = s.OlusturanKullaniciId
WHERE 1=1 and (@ogrenciUserId > 0 and ko.UserId = @ogrenciUserId) and
((@ogretmenUserId > 0) and s.OlusturanKullaniciId = @ogretmenUserId) and
(@odevAdi IS NOT NULL and LEN(@odevAdi) > 0 and o.OdevAdi = @odevAdi) and
(@odevId > 0 and ko.OdevId=@odevId)
  END
```

In my application @ogretmenUserId default value is -1,

@ogrenciUserId default value is -1,

@odevAdi null,

@odevId -1

but nothing is returning with right values  is the query false ?

**Example** I try :

odevId=1  and ogretmenUserId=1027  but nothing is returning

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I was looked Microsoft database examples I seen in Northwind database you have right I will change the name thank you for you note and spending time to telling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your conditions will work only when you pass the right values. When the default values are passed then it will fail. Example consider the first condition

```
(@ogrenciUserId > 0 and ko.UserId = @ogrenciUserId)
```

Here the default values is `-1` but the code always want it to be greater than `0` hence when `-1` is passed it will fail. Same goes with other conditions

You need `OR` condition with default values for each parameter. So when the condition will be satisfied either with default value or when it is passed with proper value.

```
WHERE  ( @ogrenciUserId = -1 
          OR ko.userid = @ogrenciUserId ) 
       AND ( @ogretmenUserId = -1 
              OR s.olusturankullaniciid = @ogretmenUserId ) 
       AND ( @odevAdi IS NULL 
              OR o.odevadi = @odevAdi ) 
       AND ( @odevId = -1 
              OR ko.odevid = @odevId )
```

Comment: Yess my query will work only if all is true  .Hmm I never think this :) Thank you for showing the right way ..

Answer (score 1):

Given the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE 1=1 and 
      (@ogrenciUserId > 0 and ko.UserId = @ogrenciUserId) and
      ((@ogretmenUserId > 0) and s.OlusturanKullaniciId = @ogretmenUserId) and
      (@odevAdi IS NOT NULL and LEN(@odevAdi) > 0 and o.OdevAdi = @odevAdi) and
      (@odevId > 0 and ko.OdevId=@odevId)
```

Plug the following values in

```
@odevId=1
@ogretmenUserId=1027
@ogrenciUserId default value is -1,
@odevAdi null,
```

The WHERE clause becomes:

```
WHERE 1=1 and 
      (-1 > 0 and ko.UserId = -1) and
      ((1027 > 0) and s.OlusturanKullaniciId = 1027) and
      (null IS NOT NULL and LEN(null) > 0 and o.OdevAdi = null) and
      (1 > 0 and ko.OdevId=1)
```

which is equivalent to

```
WHERE true and 
      false and 
      ((1027 > 0) and s.OlusturanKullaniciId = 1027) and 
      false and 
      (1 > 0 and ko.OdevId=1)
```

which is always **false**

Since it's always false based on your input parameters, regardless the content of the table rows you are scanning through, the WHERE clause always returns false and therefore no row will be selected.

Comment: I understand now,  where I was wrong.Thank you for you comment .. I plug the values thank you ;)